# Why isn't my ternary operator working in Jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a question about "className={obj.id === id ? "panel active" : "panel"}" in my code.

This project is when I click one of the images, it will stretch.

I want to show up the first image on the first loading page, and if I click one of the images, then show up another image.

How can I make choose the first child in the ternary operator?

I tried "panel active:fistChild", but I can not figure it out.

My code is

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   const [obj] = useState([
        {
          id: 1,
          backgroundImage:
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          backgroundImage:`enter code here`
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          backgroundImage:
            "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
        },
      ]);

      const [id, setId] = useState(0);

      const onclick = (id) => {
        setId(id);
      };

      return (
        <div className="container">
          {obj.map((obj) => {
            return (
              <div
                className={obj.id === id ? "panel active" : "panel"}
                onClick={(e) => onclick(obj.id)}
              >
                <img src={obj.backgroundImage} alt="" />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID of the first element is 1:

```
   const [obj] = useState([
        {
          id: 1,
```

So that's what you should use for the initial state:

```
const [id, setId] = useState(1);
```

or

```
const [id, setId] = useState(obj[0].id);
```

```js
function App() {
   const [obj] = React.useState([
      {
        id: 1,
        backgroundImage:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        backgroundImage:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        backgroundImage:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
      },
    ]);

    const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);

    const onclick = (id) => {
      setId(id);
    };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {obj.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={obj.id === id ? "panel active" : "panel"}
              onClick={(e) => onclick(obj.id)}
            >
              <img src={obj.backgroundImage} alt="" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.active {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

It may make more sense to just use the index of the image, though. Also, there's no need to call `useState` for the `obj` (which is actually an array - better to call the data structure properly to avoid confusing yourself). If it isn't dynamic for each component (like from a prop), move it out of the component entirely.

```js
const images = [
     "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
     "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
     "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
    ];
function App() {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(0);

    const onclick = (id) => {
      setId(id);
    };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {images.map((image, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              className={index === activeIndex ? "panel active" : "panel"}
              onClick={(e) => setActiveIndex(index)}
            >
              <img src={image} alt="" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
.active {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: If `const images` is static, I'd move it out of `function App()`. No need to re-create that array on every render.